# structure a large project software with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, architecture

I'm building a big project with MVC, the best way division of its structure, including Backend and customers. I can make a sample project with product management. The development experts can help me?
[Link related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474267/mvc3-and-entity-framework)

Comment: Have a look on my post for more links.hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

There is no true or false answers to this question. However, i would strongly recommend to read the following posts for a better thought:

1) [Is ASP.NET MVC a bad choice for a large enterprise project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/570705/1437962)

2) [Project structure recommendation for an opensource asp.net mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1363955/1437962)

3) [Enterprise ASP.NET MVC 3 architecture outline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6036692/1437962)

4) [Best practices for setting up an “enterprise” project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/557261/1437962)

Comment: @MrBao, any feedback on my answer, hope to get your vote.

Answer (score 0):

I also sometimes struggle on where to put certain things in my project solution.  I normally go through the source code of a couple of open source projects like [Kigg](http://kigg.codeplex.com/), [Shrinkr](http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/), [Orchard CMS](http://www.orchardproject.net/), [Nop Commerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx), etc. and try to implement a solution structure similar to how these guys did it.  The developers working on these solutions are professionals and know what's best for them.

Each project is different and should be structured accordingly.  I like the way how Kigg was structured, it is plain and simple and easy to understand, I propose that you have a look it it.

Download the source of these projects, browse and work through the code and see how they did things.

All the best :)